# Set up a NTP server which can be queried globally

Tags: networking, server, ntp

I want to set up a server (hosted on aws/or a running system in some part of the world) as an NTP server that can be queried globally.

Currently, I have modified the ntp.conf file on the node to be made the server as `server <public_ip_of_machine>`. But the problem is, on using an NTP client if I try to query time from this server, or rather on using `sudo ntpdate <ip_of_that_machine>` it says no suitable server found.

However, if I replicate the same on my local network (the server, as well as the querying node, are all on the local network) then this works perfectly fine.

I think the problem might lie in the ntp.conf file. Do I need to put some specific `restrict` lines for this to work publically as well? And no I cannot list the server on public ntp pages. Is it at all possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your *entire* `ntp.conf` file used on the server. Also include the output of `ntpq -p` on your server.

Comment: Make that the output of `ntpq -npcrv`.